# Set Eclipse to follow system classpath

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, classpath

In my Ubuntu set-up, if I do `echo $CLASSPATH`, I get something like

```
.:/usr/import/fannj-0.4.jar:/usr/import/ij.jar:/usr/import/javacpp.jar
```

which allows me to compile, via command line, classes using, say, the library ij. However, if I use the library ij in an Eclipse project, I'd get an "import cannot be resolved" error. While I know how to add ij itself to the build path of my project, it'd still be nice if Eclipse just followed what plain command-line calls to `javac` do (namely, readily link ij and other libraries). Is there a way to do this?

(Note: I managed to get all those jars to my classpath by modifying my .bashrc to export everything in /usr/import---a directory I created specifically for additional Java libs---to the system classpath.)

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You don't **want** it to do that since it would be impossible to work on a newer version of a library while it's installed on the system.  You want that level of control over what's in a project's classpath.